# Creating a co-occurence heatmap for a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, multiplication

I'm having trouble figuring out what packages/logical flow to this problem works best.

I have a dictionary like so (the list of values have been shortened for readability):

```
dict = {'term_1': ['30939593',
  '30938516',
  '30930058',
  '30928978',
  '30927713',
  '30927284',
  '30925500',
  '30923740',
  '30922102',
   ...],
'term_2': ['30931235',
  '30938516',
  '30928978',
  '30922102',
  '30858642',
  '30828702',
  '30815562',
  '30805732',
  '30766735',
  '30746412',
  '30740089',
   ...],
   etc. 
}
```

Between the two terms I've listed there are three values that co-occur (30938516,30928978, and 30922102).

The dictionary contains about 1800 keys, each with a list of values that are corresponding IDs, and some of these lists may be 100,000 values long.

I want to be able to visualize, in a heatmap, the degree of similarity between every term in the dictionary based on co-occurrence of IDs within the list of values. As in, the x and y axis of the heatmap would be labelled by the same terms in sequential order and each cell of the heatmap would show the overlap of IDs between one term and another term by counts of how many co-occurring values there are (in this case, the co-occurrence between term_1 and term_2 would be 3). This would be repeated for all 1800 terms, leading to an 1800x1800 heatmap.

---

Regarding the values as strings, I've tried converting the dictionary into two dataframes: one where the terms are the column headers and the values are listed by column, and the other where the terms are the row headers and the values are listed by row.

Firstly, I converted the dictionary into a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient = 'index')
df = df[df.columns[0:]].apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str).astype(str)),
    axis = 1
)
```

However, this only converts the dictionary into a single column of length 1800. I would also need to find a way to expand the dataframe so that each column is duplicated 1800 times.

Once I have this 1800 x 1800 column, I would transpose it.

```
df_transposed = df.T
```

If we are to treat each set of cells of the dataframe that we are comparing as two lists, we can approach each comparison like so

```
l1 = ['30939593',
  '30938516',
  '30930058',
  '30928978',
  '30927713',
  '30927284',
  '30925500',
  '30923740',
  '30922102']
l2 = ['30931235',
  '30938516',
  '30928978',
  '30922102',
  '30858642',
  '30828702',
  '30815562',
  '30805732',
  '30766735',
  '30746412',
  '30740089']
from collections import Counter
c = len(list((Counter(l1) & Counter(l2)).elements()))

c = 3
```

However, I am unsure of how to loop through this within the confines of a dataframe

I want to compare each cell of the 1800x1800 grid such that each grid contains an integer value of how many co-occuring IDs there were in each cell, between each term. I would then convert this 1800x1800 grid of integers to a heatmap.

Comment: To make this more understandable I suggest you simplify the data given. try using a dictionary with a few keys, and a few values where the values are digits 1-5 or 1-10. purposefully make some of the values overlap to demonstrate a representative dataset. Then show the expected output that you're looking to get. 
`d = {'a':[1, 4, 5], 'b':[3], 'c':[5, 5, 4, 2, 1]}` for example. Its much easier to show a heatmap of what you're looking for with only 3 keys and numbers 1-5, but it still gets your point across

Comment: @MattW. Thats a good suggestion. I'll do that first and edit my post, right now it is a bit too abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to calculate the overlaps first based on the dictionary `d` and then make the required DataFrame with `pivot`:

```
x = [(k1, k2, len(set(d1) & set(d2))) for k1,d1 in d.items() for k2,d2 in d.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(x).pivot(index=0, columns=1, values=2)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
1       term_1  term_2
0                     
term_1       9       3
term_2       3      11
```

And, of course, for the heatmap:

```
sns.heatmap(df)
```

Output:

[image: picture]